# New iPhone YouTube App - How do you play the video in a box?

Tags: iphone, youtube-api

The new YouTube App for iPhone plays a YouTube video in a designated area on the screen when in portrait mode without the video taking over the entire phone. This is the first time I've ever seen this done. Can you please tell me

1. How is this accomplished?
2. What options are available (can the scrubber be hidden, a la the chromeless player)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an enhancement filed with youtube for being able to do this. It has been sent to the engineering team at youtube, but we dont know if/when they will take it up.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3007

Comment: It's already being done in their new app for iOS, which means it's already possible. I'm asking how it's done.